# Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x8B\x93\xE6\xB5\xB7' for column 'bookName' at row 1

Tags: navicat

When I add row in my table: book use navicat, there comes an issue:

> **Error**
>
> Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x8B\x93\xE6\xB5\xB7' for column 'bookName' at row 1

[image]

Why?

**EDIT**

I run  `show create table book;`

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `bookName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `InsertTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UpdateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `bookstore_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `fk_book_bookstore` (`bookstore_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_bookstore` FOREIGN KEY (`bookstore_Id`) REFERENCES `bookstore` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='book'
```

Comment: can you show the sql you create the table book?

Comment: @aircraft how to show the sql?

Comment: add query, type in  `show create table book;` then run this line.

Answer (score 0):

You see the `CHARSET=latin1` at the table, your book table default charset is `latin1`, you should change the charset.

```
alter table book default character set utf8;
```